# Whatss the difference between Open in Live Server and Open in Default browser

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

My website is showing difference on vsc live server and normal browser.

This is Live Server [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nspRM.jpg)

And this is normal browser [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcyEk.jpg)

why this both is have differents?which one i should use

Answer (score 1):

Using Live Server would **instantly reload the page** when you make any changes.

On the other hand, when using a normie browser you would **have to reload the page** to reflect the changes every time.

Guess you now know which one to use. Live Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you set the zoom on the live server.
There is no visual difference between live server and normal

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + 0 (zero) to set the live server size to 100 % and hopefully that both pages with and without liver server will be visually the same.
The difference is that live server will update it automatically without refreshing the page